# UIButton Animation for IPhone

Tags: xcode, uianimation

I am new to xcode, but I have been searching around for solution, and I have tried many different methods, but none of it is working.  **I am trying to make `UIButton` flip to the reverse side by adding animation to it.  This will occur when program loads up, so user can just sit back and watch a whole bunch of buttons flip over and over.**

The problem that I am having is that the animation seems to take place before screen even loads because I can see a different view (to show that button is flipped), as soon as the program loads, but I cannot see the animation taking place.

**What I have done:**

I created a main view controller and inside the controller I have different subviews and within those subviews, I have `UIButtons`.  I tried to add a delay to my animation, but it still does not fix it.  I don't know if the problem could occur because I create subviews and buttons and then animate under **`- (void)viewDidLoad.`**  I also tried to create another subview and put just one button into that subview, which will create 2 subviews and each having just one button and animate by flipping between the subviews, but I still get the same problem.  The animation still happened before the screen even loads up, instead of during the run time of the program.

I am attaching part of the code that I did to this one.

```
CGRect button20subviewFrame = CGRectMake(242, 370, 70, 83);
UIView *button20subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:button20subviewFrame];
UIButton *button20 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button20 addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToDetailView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button20 setTitle:@"Button20" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button20.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0 , 70 , 83);
UIImage *button20Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"t1.png"];
[button20 setImage:button20Image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button20subview addSubview:button20];
[self.view addSubview:button20subview];

UIButton *button21 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button21 addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToDetailView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
button21.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 83);
UIImage *button21Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"t2.png"];
[button21 setImage:button21Image forState:UIControlStateNormal];


//animation part
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 delay:2 options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{
    [button20 removeFromSuperview];
    [button20subview addSubview:button21];
}completion:^(BOOL finished){

}];
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` is the problem. It gets called when the view is done loading, which is before it is put on screen. `viewDidAppear` should do what you're looking for.

In addition to this, you may want to call `[button20 removeFromSuperview]` in the animations completion handler to ensure that the front of the button isn't removed while the animation is still taking place.

E.x:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 delay:2 options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{
    [button20subview addSubview:button21];
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
     if(finished){
         [button20 removeFromSuperview];
     }
}];
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the answer, but unfortunately it still produces the same result that I got earlier.  It just animated before the screen finish loading.